# Is there a way for a SecurityManager in java to selectively grant ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")?

Tags: java, reflection, securitymanager

Is there any way for a SecurityManager in Java to selectively grant ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks") depending on the details of what setAccessible() is being called on? I don't see any way for this to be done.

For some sandboxed code, it would be very useful (such as for running various dynamic JVM languages) to allow the setAccessible() reflection API to be called, but **only** when setAccessible() is called on a method/field of a class that originates in the sandboxed code.

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions other than selective granting of ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks") if this isn't possible? Perhaps it would be safe to grant in all cases if SecurityManager.checkMemberAccess() is sufficiently restrictive?

Answer (score 12):

Maybe looking at the call stack would be enough for your purposes? Something like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission;
import java.security.Permission;

public class Test {
    private static int foo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
                if (perm instanceof ReflectPermission && "suppressAccessChecks".equals(perm.getName())) {
                    for (StackTraceElement elem : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
                        if ("Test".equals(elem.getClassName()) && "badSetAccessible".equals(elem.getMethodName())) {
                            throw new SecurityException();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        goodSetAccessible(); // works
        badSetAccessible(); // throws SecurityException
    }

    private static void goodSetAccessible() throws Exception {
        Test.class.getDeclaredField("foo").setAccessible(true);
    }

    private static void badSetAccessible() throws Exception {
        Test.class.getDeclaredField("foo").setAccessible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using byte code weaving with a library like [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net/). Instead of using the standard `ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")` permission, you can create a custom permission and replace the `AccessibleObject.setAccessible` methods with custom methods that check your custom permission using Byte Buddy transformations.

One possible way for this custom permission to work is for it to base access on the classloader of the caller and the object that access is being modified on. Using this allows isolated code (code loaded from a separate with it's own class loader) to call `setAccessible` on classes in its own jar, but not Standard Java classes or your own application classes.

Such a permission might look like:

```
public class UserSetAccessiblePermission extends Permission {
  private final ClassLoader loader;

  public UserSetAccessiblePermission(ClassLoader loader) {
    super("userSetAccessible");
    this.loader = loader;
  }  

  @Override
  public boolean implies(Permission permission) {
    if (!(permission instanceof UserSetAccessiblePermission)) {
      return false;
    }
    UserSetAccessiblePermission that = (UserSetAccessiblePermission) permission;
    return that.loader == this.loader;
  }

  // equals and hashCode omitted  

  @Override
  public String getActions() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

This is how I chose to implement this permission, but it could instead be a package or class whitelist or blacklist.

Now with this permission you can create a stub class that will replace the `AccessibleObject.setAcessible` method to instead use this permission.

```
public class AccessibleObjectStub {
  private final static Permission STANDARD_ACCESS_PERMISSION =
      new ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks");

  public static void setAccessible(@This AccessibleObject ao, boolean flag)
      throws SecurityException {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
      Permission permission = STANDARD_ACCESS_PERMISSION;
      if (isFromUserLoader(ao)) {
        try {
          permission = getUserAccessPermission(ao);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // Ignore. Use standard permission.
        }
      }

      sm.checkPermission(permission);
    }
  }

  private static Permission getUserAccessPermission(AccessibleObject ao)
      throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException,
      NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassLoader aoClassLoader = getAccessibleObjectLoader(ao);
    return new UserSetAccessiblePermission(aoClassLoader);
  }

  private static ClassLoader getAccessibleObjectLoader(AccessibleObject ao) {
    return AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<ClassLoader>() {
      @Override
      public ClassLoader run() {
        if (ao instanceof Executable) {
          return ((Executable) ao).getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader();
        } else if (ao instanceof Field) {
          return ((Field) ao).getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown AccessibleObject type: " + ao.getClass());
      }
    });
  }

  private static boolean isFromUserLoader(AccessibleObject ao) {
    ClassLoader loader = getAccessibleObjectLoader(ao);

    if (loader == null) {
      return false;
    }

    // Check that the class loader instance is of a custom type
    return UserClassLoaders.isUserClassLoader(loader);
  }
}
```

With these two classes in place you can now use Byte Buddy to build a transformer for transforming the Java `AccessibleObject` to use your stub.

The first step to create the transformer is to create a Byte Buddy type pool that includes the bootstrap classes and a jar file containing your stubs.

```
final TypePool bootstrapTypePool = TypePool.Default.of(
new ClassFileLocator.Compound(
    new ClassFileLocator.ForJarFile(jarFile),
    ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of(null)));
```

Next use reflections to get a reference to the `AccessObject.setAccessible0` method. This is a private method that actually modifies the accessibility if the call to `setAccessible` passes permission checks.

```
Method setAccessible0Method;
try {
  String setAccessible0MethodName = "setAccessible0";
  Class[] paramTypes = new Class[2];
  paramTypes[0] = AccessibleObject.class;
  paramTypes[1] = boolean.class;
  setAccessible0Method = AccessibleObject.class
      .getDeclaredMethod(setAccessible0MethodName, paramTypes);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

With these two pieces the transformer can be built.

```
AgentBuilder.Transformer transformer = new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
  @Override
  public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(
      DynamicType.Builder<?> builder,
      TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    return builder.method(
        ElementMatchers.named("setAccessible")
            .and(ElementMatchers.takesArguments(boolean.class)))
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(
            bootstrapTypePool.describe(
                "com.leacox.sandbox.security.stub.java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObjectStub")
                .resolve())
            .andThen(MethodCall.invoke(setAccessible0Method).withThis().withAllArguments()));
  }
}
```

The final step is to then install the Byte Buddy Java agent and perform the transformation. The jar containing the stubs must also be appended to the bootstrap class path. This is necessary because the `AccessibleObject` class will be loaded by the bootstrap loader, thus any stubs must be loaded there as well.

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
// Append the jar containing the stub replacement to the bootstrap classpath
instrumentation.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(jarFile);

AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
       .disableClassFormatChanges()
       .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
       .ignore(none()); // disable default ignores so we can transform Java classes
       .type(ElementMatchers.named("java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject"))
       .transform(transformer)
       .installOnByteBuddyAgent();
```

This will work when using a SecurityManager and isolating both the stubs classes and the code that you are applying the selective permissions to in separate jars that are loaded at runtime. Having to load the jars at runtime rather than having them as standard dependencies or bundled libs complicates things a bit, but this seems to be a requirement for isolating untrusted code when using the `SecurityManager`.

My Github repo [sandbox-runtime](https://github.com/johnlcox/sandbox-runtime) has a full, in-depth, example of a sandboxed runtime environment with execution of isolated untrusted code and more selective reflection permissions. I also have a blog post with more detail on just the [selective setAccessible permissions](http://john.leacox.com/2016/07/19/selective-setaccessible-permissions-using-byte-buddy-and-the-java-securitymanager/) pieces.

Answer (score 0):

FWI: Since setAccessible seems only to have a valid use-case with serialization, I would think you might often get away with simply denying it outright.

That said, I am interested in how one does this sort of thing in general because I too have to write a security manager to block dynamically loaded code from doing things that our application container code needs to be able to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, some dynamic JVM lanauges are unfortunately fairly setAccessible-happy, calling it even for public methods they don't need to call it for. Plus there are use cases like that serialization you mention, or some modes of operation of dependency injection frameworks, that would preferred to not be needlessly blocking.

Comment: Hmmm. Not aware of those other use cases - I have long thought that setAccessible is the biggest security screw up Sun ever made with Java.