# Setting the Java SecurityManager for one method only

Tags: java, permissions, securitymanager

I have a method A which might look like following:

```
public double A{
  if (secM == null) {
    secM = new SecurityManager();
    System.setSecurityManager(secM);
  }
  //do something and return a double

}
```

The problem is that once the SecurityManager is set, it is for the entire project, but I only need it to be for the class this method is in.
How can I tell the SecurityManager to only verify the permissions for this method/class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What actions do you want the SecurityManager to prevent, and which do you want to allow? SecurityManager is more often used to control particular actions by *any* method, rather than actions by a single method.

However, it can do the latter too, by creating a custom SecurityManager that examines the call stack - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909559/699224) for an example - is this what you need?

You can provide the system-wide SecurityManager with a policy tailored to your application, so you can permit most things but prevent a small set of actions. The permissions you can control are [listed here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html).

**Update**: you *might* be able to do this more elegantly by pulling your method out into a separate class, that can be loaded separately (by a different classloader) than your other classes. See [this example](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch06_02.htm). Then you can do a trivial check with the classloader rather than checking the full stack trace. However, I'm not familiar with this method - there may be implications if classes from the two separate classloaders need to interact...

Comment: The method shouldn't be allowed to do anything, it should only be used for calculations etc. Maybe what you suggested is going to work, I'm not sure though.

Comment: I tried the answer you suggested and it works so far, but it  isn't that elegant. Is there no other way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if by modifying the classloader I can achieve what I need. I have found another approach over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application. However I don't know what the variable "pass" in the second approach with the SecurityManager is used for?

Comment: These approaches are all fairly similar. The idea in the one you linked is that you can turn off the security manager again after running the untrusted code. `pass` is a password or secret used to authenticate to the securitymanager and thus ensure that the untrusted code can't just disable the security manager and do what it likes!

Comment: Okay, I get it so far, but what I still don't quite understand is how I can check whether the SecurityManager is active for all methods, or just for the one in question? Or do I need to implement the answer you suggested initially instead of the placeholder "//override checkXXX methods" (in option 2 of the link I provided earlier)?