# Reflection Security

Tags: java, security, reflection, policy, securitymanager

How to enforce reflection security by not allow the `Method`, `Field`, `Constructor` object to call `setAccessible(true)` ? SecurityPolicy File or something else?

Normally for stand-alone Java applications there is no `SecurityManager` registered.

I using this `System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());`

This approach will work for calling methods.

I would like to enforce the whole jar or client code that uses the jar is not allow to call `setAccessible(true);`

Any better approach ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um, it *does* work for setAccessible. See:

```
class A {
  private String method1() {
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

and

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    Class clazz = A.class;
    Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method1");
    m.setAccessible(true);
  }
}
```

Results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
        at B.main(B.java:8)
```

One reason it might've not worked for you is that according to comments in [this post](http://neuroning.com/2007/02/19/violating-javas-privacy) it didn't use to work in Java 1.5, but works in 6 and thereafter.

---

Edit: to deny it for specific jars, you need to either use a policy file, example:

```
// specific file
grant codeBase "file:/test/path/tools.jar" {
  // no permissions for this one
};

// default to giving all
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

There's two ways of specifying the policy file, either give it as additions to default, or give only those that are specified ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#DefaultLocs)):

> If you use
>
> ```
> java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==someURL SomeApp
> ```
>
> (note the double equals) then just the specified policy file will be
>   used; all the ones indicated in the security properties file will be
>   ignored.

...or implement a custom security manager, which [doesn't look that hard](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/extendsSecurityManager.htm). Haven't done that myself though.

Comment: There seems to be [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315066/is-there-a-way-for-a-securitymanager-in-java-to-selectively-grant-reflectpermiss?rq=1) about the same subject, too.

Comment: I want to enforce no calling to setAccessible method in my apps.

Comment: @peterwkc yes, and I've answered that you can do that with SecurityManager?

Comment: How to do that with SecurityManager ? u mean custom security manager ?

Comment: @peterwkc no, using standard one, like in my example. but you'd need to use either a policy file or a custom security manager to deny it only for specific jar(s).