# how does spring implement this technology?

Tags: java, spring

today,i learned that we could use spring's @AutoWired annotation to complete auto-injection,
@AutoWired could be used in many conditions ,like

```
@AutoWired
public void setInstrument(Instrument instrument){
  this.instrument = instrument;
}
```

but we can also put the `@AutoWired` on a private field,like this

```
@AutoWired
private Instrument instrument;
```

i was wondering ,how could spring inject an object into a private field,i know we could use reflection of java to get some meta data,when i use reflection to set a object on a private field ,here comes a problem ,following is the stacktrace

```
 java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.wire.with.annotation.Main can not access a member of class com.wire.with.annotation.Performer with modifiers "private"
```

some body can explain it ? why spring could inject an object into a private field with no setter method . thanks  a lot

Comment: Reflection, BCEL, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done using reflection you need to `Filed.setAccessible(true)` to access the `private` fields.

```
privateField.setAccessible(true);//works ,if java security manager is disable
```

**update:-**

eg-

```
public class MainClass {
    private String string="Abcd";

    public static void main(String... arr) throws SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException{
        MainClass mainClass=new MainClass();
        Field stringField=MainClass.class.getDeclaredField("string");
        stringField.setAccessible(true);//making field accessible 
        /*if SecurityManager enable then,  
        java.security.AccessControlException: access denied will be thrown here*/
        stringField.set(mainClass, "Defgh");//seting value to field as it's now accessible
        System.out.println("value of string ="+stringField.get(mainClass));//getting value from field then printing it on console
    }
}
```

Java Security manager(if enable) also prevents Spring from accessing private fields

Comment: @Uwe And if the security manager forbids it, Spring DI doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot to set [`setAccessible(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) on the field you're trying to access:

```java
public class Main {

    private String foo;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // the Main instance
        Main instance = new Main();
        // setting the field via reflection
        Field field = Main.class.getDeclaredField("foo");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(instance, "bar");
        // printing the field the "classic" way
        System.out.println(instance.foo); // prints "bar"
    }

}
```

Please read [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14639753/1225328) too.

Comment: @kevin You're welcome! If my answer suited your needs, don't forget to  [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186921) (same for [the other questions you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2299654/kevin?tab=questions) :)