# Java SecurityManager: block Reflection to specific class

Tags: java, securitymanager

Let's say I have a package (`com.example.private`) with some classes that contain sensitive information. The methods and fields are `private` or `package private` to prevent access under normal circumstances.

I am aware that Reflection can be used to access these properties regardless of their privacy modifier by using the `setAccessible(true)` method. Because of this, I would like to use a `SecurityManager` to block access to Reflection. However, since Reflection is used as part of my publicly accessible API, I can't block it entirely.

I have tried using the `suppressAccessChecks` permission check, which works, but it breaks parts of my API as mentioned before.

**TL;DR:**
Is it possible to use a `SecurityManager` to block Reflection on a specific class or package?

Edit: this thread details how to block Reflect from a specific CALLER.
My objective is to block Reflection to a specific TARGET.

[Is there a way for a SecurityManager in java to selectively grant ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315066/is-there-a-way-for-a-securitymanager-in-java-to-selectively-grant-reflectpermiss)